# Bash array values as variables

Tags: arrays, bash

Is it possible to use array values as variables?
For example, i have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE=$(curl -k -s $1 | sed 's/{//g;s/}//g;s/,/"\n"/g;s/:/=/g;s/"//g' | awk -F"=" '{ print $1 }')
JSON=$(curl -k -s $1 | sed 's/{//g;s/}//g;s/,/"\n"/g;s/:/=/g;s/"//g' | awk -F"=" '{ print $NF }')
data=$2
readarray -t prot_array <<< "$SOURCE"
readarray -t pos_array <<< "$JSON"

for ((i=0; i<${#prot_array[@]}; i++)); do
echo  "${prot_array[i]}" "${pos_array[i]}" | sed 's/NOK/0/g;s/OK/1/g' | grep $2 | awk -F' ' '{ print $2,$3,$4 }'
done
```

EDIT:

I just added: `grep $2 | awk -F' ' '{ print $2,$3,$4 }'`

Usage:

```
./json.sh URL
```

Sample (very short) output:

```
DATABASE 1
STATUS 1
```

I don't want to echo out all the lines, i  would like to use DATABASE STATUS as variable $DATABASE and echo that out.
I just need DATABASE (or any other) value from command line.
Is it somehow possible to use something like this?

```
./json.sh URL $DATABASE
```

Happy to explain more if needed.

EDIT:
curl output without any formattings etc:

```
{  
   "VERSION":"R3.1",
   "STATUS":"OK",
   "DATABASES":{  
      "READING":"OK"
   },
   "TIMESTAMP":"2017-03-08-16-20-35"
}
```

Output using script:

```
VERSION R3.1 
STATUS 1 
DATABASES 1 
TIMESTAMP 2017-03-08-16-21-54
```

What i want is described before. For example use DATABASE as varible $DATABASE and somehow get the value "1"

EDIT:

Random json from uconn.edu

```
./json.sh https://github.uconn.edu/raw/nam12023/novaLauncher/master/manifest.json
```

Another:

```
./json.sh https://gitlab.uwe.ac.uk/dc2-roskilly/angular-qs/raw/master/.npm/nan/2.4.0/package/package.json
```

Last output begins with:

```
name nan
version 2.4.0
```

From command line: ./json.sh URL version

At leats it works for me.

Comment: Why can't you use a proper `JSON` parser for processing json output from `cURL`? instead of `sed`? It makes your task a lot simpler.

Comment: Please post your output from `curl` and the exact output you are looking to get

Comment: Please update it as part of the question and remove it from the comments

Comment: So `OK` corresponds to `1`, is it? How is your expected output generated?

Comment: Where does the version number `R13.1369` come from? (The timestamps in your input and output don't match either, so I suspect you aren't showing the output for the given input.)

Comment: OK corresponds to, NOK corresponds to 0. Any other output would be just text. @Inian
chepner, i just modified it little bit, sorry - i'll fix it.

Comment: I have it installed, but i was not also make variable out of DATABASE etc.
Maybe there's a way ..

Comment: @Jaur If you use `awk` and `sed` together in a pipe then you are very likely using one tool too much, meaning you are not using the tools efficiently.

Comment: I'm sure you are right. But @ the moment it works, kind of. I get the needed output. Remaining question is: how to assign DATABASE as variable (or any other line)

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use `jq` something like this:

```
$ curl -k -s "$1" | jq --arg d DATABASES -r '
    "VERSION \(.VERSION)",
    "STATUS \(if .STATUS == "OK" then 1 else 0 end)",
    "DATABASES \(if .[$d].READING == "OK" then 1 else 0 end)", 
    "TIMESTAMP \(.TIMESTAMP)"
'
VERSION R3.1
STATUS 1
DATABASES 1
TIMESTAMP 2017-03-08-16-20-35
```

(I'm probably missing a simpler way to convert a boolean value to an integer.)

Quick explanation:

1. The `,`-separated strings each become a separate output line.
2. The `-r` option outputs a raw string, rather than a JSON string value.
3. The name of the database field is passed using the `--arg` option.
4. `\(...)` is `jq`'s interpolation operator; the contents are evaluated as a JSON expression and the result is inserted into the string.

Comment: Oddly enough, you don't, but putting the space there is a good idea anyway.

Comment: Good answer. Just a side note: You don't need to build a list using `[ ]` and then `join("\n")` at the end. Just separate individual filters by `,`. `jq` will print the results of them by default on a separate line(s).

Comment: So, the output is the same. Good, but i need to assing DATABASE somehow as variable. Or any other first sting in a output.
P.S behind my URL could be much longer json. At the moment i was testing my script agains another json, much longer, different output lines etc. Output basically is in same format: "SOMESTING somevalue"

Comment: `DATABASE` *is* passed as a variable, assuming it is always a key mapping to another object with a `READING` key. It can be generalized further, but you're going to have to be clearer about what other inputs you might see. (Or are you just saying that the output should use the same string that is input?)

Comment: @hek2mgl I started with a multiline string, then broke it into the form shown for readability. I did forget just using a list of separate filters, though.

Comment: It does not answer the question guys @hek2mgl

Comment: First, it wasn't me, it was @chepner who answered but imo you need to phrase your question more precisely if this answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: It's written before:
I don't want to echo out all the lines, i would like to use DATABASE STATUS as variable $DATABASE and echo that out
It's quite understandable ... i think.
I'm no accusing anyone, but this 5 "thumb up" at the moment is not the answer. Sure thing, this answer could help somebody - no doubt about that!